# Hibernate SessionFactory Mappings is not reloaded

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I'm using Hibernate with this SessionFactory configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>mappings/File1.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" scope="singleton"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1529:VIOLET" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

It works fine until I add one more XML mapping file as follows:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>mappings/File1.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>mappings/File2.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

The added mapping "File2.hbm.xml" is not affected at all. I even try to set the class in "File2.hbm.xml" with an invalid name but there is no error shown in Hibernate (When I do that in "File1.hbm.xml", there is exception).

Could you tell me why the mapping "File2.hbm.xml" is not affected? I use Eclipse and Tomcat, does it cache some where. I already tried to clean Tomcat and restart my PC but it does not help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file? Also your configuration is flawed never set the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` if you use spring, setting it to thread breaks proper tx management (if you are using springs tx management). Also note that the `hibernate.c3p0` properties are useless as you are injecting a `DataSource` yourself.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not the config file. As I mentioned, my code works but only the File2.hbm.xml is not affected. I clean tomcat work directory and the problem is solved

Comment: The fact that it works doesn't mean it is correct :) but alas. Just wanted to point to your configuration flaws and asking a clarifaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Tomcat cached the old config file. After cleaning (Server -> Clean Tomcat Work Directory), the new file takes effect.